# Audit Baselines in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, audit, baseline

I am wondering if it is possible to view the entire project's baselines that were made in an overall EA project over time similar to the Auditing feature. I know baselines can be viewed for particular packages but is there a way to view all the baselines made within the whole project as to see who changed what and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A baseline just contains a model snapshot, not what someone has changed. This is only available with the Audit feature. Or maybe LieberLieber's Lemontree is worth a look. I just know that they provide git-integration but don't know how that would work (looks rather like black magic or voodoo to me since that means XMI merging).

The only thing you can get from EA are the names of the baselines and such information (e.g. ProjectInterface.GetBaselines and the like).

To get the baselines themselves just perform this SQL:

```
Repository.SQLQuery("SELECT * FROM t_document WHERE ElementType = 'Baseline'")
```

The column `BinContent` contains the packed baseline as XMI export. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The earlier part of my question (which i reworded for clarity) is still unanswered. Is there a way to view the entire collection of baselines that were made in an EA project overall?

Comment: See my addition